# The time complexity of count nodes in a binary tree with recursion, is a little more than o(n) correct?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

Take this python code as an example

```
def count_nodes(node: Node):
if(node is None):
    return 0

return 1 + count_nodes(node.left) + count_nodes(node.right)
```

On the leafs, the recursion will point to left and right and return 0

Soo in a very big binary tree the time complexity will be:

> o(n) + the number of leafs * 2

Is that correct?, or I am misunderstanding the idea of time complexity

Comment: Note that [big-O and little-o are not the same](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/uADA/13/lectures/app-b.pdf). Can you clarify whether you are really asking about little-o here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, you attached you are traversing only those nodes which are valid (or which exists), so in this case if you have `n` nodes you are traversing only `n` nodes.

It's no way wrong to write: `o(n) + the number of leafs * 2` but eventually it would become: `o(n)` in terms of Big-O.